# Scaling issue on services processing data on NFS

Tags: linux, nfs

We are facing an interesting scaling problem in our system. I have some idea towards a solution, but I would love your advice on the subject, before starting on the solution itself.

We have multiple services processing on the files shared through NFS server. Each file is around 2GB, and each service could process up to ~15 files in one instance. The servers are connected via 10 Gbps network, and NFS is created atop RAID 10 supporting 1000MB/s throughput. The nature of services is that they create a thread lock on the file until the process is complete and the process acts on only a few chunks data in parallel.

So our services are increasing in number. Recently we started observing a significant delay in the processes. By significant, I mean 3-4x delay. Profiling the services, we figured out that most of the time spent was on file IO rather than processing itself. So my first intuition is that the delay is due to a couple of things:

- Collective access to data maxes out the bandwidth
- Process having to wait for chunks of data to be loaded on every iteration which puts overhead to IO orchestration.
- Thread lock that services have on files

And the idea that I thought could work is, each service copies data to that service and copies results back to NFS after processing. With this approach, I am not sure if we can solve the issue with bandwidth, but the other issues should be solved. Since it's a lot of effort to implement this solution in multiple services, I would like to be sure if it works. What do you guys think? Please do let me know.

EDIT

- The NFS Client version is 4.2 on Debian GNU/Linux 10 with kernel version 4.15.0-118-generic
- The NFS Server version is 4 on Cent OS 7 with kernel version 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64
- Mount options used are hard,async,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,proto=tcp,namelen=1000

Comment: Can you please update the question with the client /server OS versions and mount options.

Comment: @kofemann I have updated the question with the information